# How do I get the post_detail page to work?

Tags: django

Following is my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='list'),
    path('<slug>/', views.post_detail, name='detail'),
]
```

My views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, slug):
    post_det = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'singlepost': post_det})
```

And my post_detail.html page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
              {% for post in posts %}
              <div class="post col-md-10 shadow mx-auto">
                <!-- post-thumbnail -->
                <div class="post-thumbnail">
                    <img src="{{singlepost.thumb.url}}">
                </div>
                <!-- /post-thumbnail -->
                <h2 class="post-title bg-dark text-light pad1 text-center">{{ singlepost.title }}</h2>
                <p class="post-content">{{ singlepost.body }}</p>
                <p class="post-info grey border pad1">{{ singlepost.date }}</p>
               </div>
              {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Screenshot from the error page:
[Django - Page Not Found Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTDBm.png)

What appears to be the problem here? Keep in mind that I'm new to django, however, this is the first time I come across an url such as the one noted in the error report.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes,
In urls.py,

```
path('detail/<slug:slug>/', views.#restofyoururl ),
```

You have not added your homepage html, so check if you have added the url correctly. In your homepage html

```
<a href={% url 'blog:detail' post.slug %}> {{post.title}}#add as per your model </a>
```

Note : You can add class based view for your detail page.